# Angular Interceptor not working when making API calls

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a loader to inform the user that the API is still loading but it doesn't seem to work, i tried using a

```
setTimeout(() => {}, 3000);
```

to make the service last longer but i just get the data showed slower.
The code i'm using is from this github https://github.com/shaheershukur/Market-Web-Application/tree/master/market check for *Part6 - Progress Loader, Http Interceptor*

To make the API calls i use `httpClient.get()` and each components has functions that make calls using the services i made like this

```
getUpdate(){
   
    this.service.getUpdateAPI().subscribe(response => { 
       ...
    }); 
  }
```

and this is the interceptor code that doesnt seem to get any http requests

```
constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      
      finalize(
        () => {
          this.loaderService.isLoading.next(false);
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

How can i use this interceptor while im using lazy loading, it seems that i cant declare `HttpClientModule` in both `bootstrap.module.ts` and `app.module.ts`? any idea on how to make them both work?

Comment: We need a little bit more to go on. Did you register the Interceptor in the AppModule? `{provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:CLASS_NAME}`.

Comment: yes i used it like this `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true }`, the code regarding interceptor is on github

Comment: what version of Angular you use?

Comment: try `provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())` in bootstrap function in `main.ts` if you use standalone component for bootstrapping

Comment: im using angular 14

Answer (score -1):

The setTimeout(() => {}, 3000); should be in the finalize

```
 finalize(
    () => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
         this.loaderService.isLoading.next(false);
      },3000)
    }
  )
```

Comment: but the problem is if the problem was there the variable should be set to true and i can see the loader, but is not intercepting the request, i tried using your way and added a console log and i got nothing

Comment: can you check last edit on my question?